# What evidence exists for / against the claim that Hamas wants genocide (and / or that Israel does not)?

Tags: israel, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

Most positions I've heard regarding the war seem to fall into two broad categories:

1. Intent doesn't matter; only outcomes do (usually followed by arguments about whether Israel is committing war crimes; whether they are justified; etc.)
2. Intent matters a great deal. This is usually followed by the claim that Hamas would surely exterminate all jews if they could, but not vice versa (as evidenced by Israel not having done so) and therefore Hamas must be stopped at almost *any* cost.

There is a lot of subtlety in (2). Perhaps Israel would indeed perpetrate genocide if not for the certain global backlash. Maybe Hamas would *not* if certain conditions were met (though perhaps nothing short of being given all of Israel -- or maybe not even that would suffice). Hamas's founding charter seems pretty clear, but later charters have softened their stance. There also exist quotes like this:

> Hamas is not hostile to Jews because they are Jews. We are hostile to them because they occupied our land and expelled our people.... We did not say we want to throw the Jews in the sea or feed them to sharks. We just said that there is a land called occupied Palestine. It was burglarized and it needs to be returned to the Palestinian people. (Ismail Hanieh, Hamas leader, January 18, 2006, AP, as cited in [Hamas in Their Own Words](https://www.adl.org/resources/news/hamas-their-own-words))

But it is hard for a layperson like me to get a handle on the bigger picture; to cut through propaganda; etc.

To keep this question objective, I'd like to see a comprehensive set of evidence for / against the claim that the motivations of the two entities are materially different.

Comment: [WSJ against Hamas: 'In English they beg for aid, in Arabic they pledge a massacre'](https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/379756)

Comment: The evidence you seek may be difficult to come by. Public statements are often not an accurate representation of actual beliefs and goals (compare Trump's statements about the stolen election with what has eventually been discovered about his actual knowledge).

Comment: The question makes sense. But even if it was possible to answer it by collecting all the evidence available, the essence of the question is hypothetical: if the circumstances made it possible, would the Hamas/Israel actually commit a genocide? What if Hamas was in a dominant military position but had diplomatic pressure from the international community? What if the IDF was only a guerilla militant group? In a parallel universe, what if the peace process had been continued? There can't be any objective answer to any of these questions.

Comment: @Erwan *In a parallel universe, what if the peace process had been continued?* - Hamas explicitly rejects the peace process and any agreements reached within its context. *What if the IDF was only a guerilla militant group?* - IDF did emerge out of guerilla groups like Hagana and Irgun - because all of them were ready to accept a state on however small piece of land they were given, and regardless of which of them represented the ruling party.

Comment: @RogerV. Hamas rejects the peace process in the context where the rival PA accepts it and Israel refuses to negotiate with Hamas anyway. So politically there's currently no advantage for them to accept the peace process. Same thing for the IDF which started as a terrorist group and ended as the official army of a recognized country. What if Israel had never been recognized by anybody and the IDF was still an illegal militant group? The actions and words of any entity depend on the context, they are not bound to a specific role or by their origin.

Comment: May I take the liberty to venture so far as to say that one could infer from the fact Hamas tries to commit genocide and celebrates it, that they want to commit genocide, and from the fact that Israel tries to avoid killing civilians that they don't want to commit genocide. Around 10,000 civilian deaths out of a population of millions in one of the most densely populated areas on earth is extremely good (this isn't factoring in the hundreds if not thousands of Hamas rockets that malfunction and land in Gaza).

Comment: When one looks into the chant 'from the river to the sea', with minimal thought and a simple glance at a map they would come to the startling realization that from the river to the sea encompasses... Everything. So they can soften their stance by saying they support a Palestinian state, but know that means a Palestinian state and no Israel.

Comment: And action speaks louder than words - many Palestinian leaders were offered by many Israeli leaders the opportunity to have a Palestinian state, yet they all rejected it. Hmm...

Comment: And Hamas didn't diffrentiate between the evil colonizer and the peaceful Jews - many of those killed on October 7th were lifelong peace activists who dedicated parts, if not all, of their life to the cause of Palestinian rights, freedom, and statehood. But they recieved a bullet in the head just the same.

Comment: You see, Hamas and all these other groups have no interest in a 2 state solution. In fact, the 2 state solution was tried before - in 1948. It fell apart fairly quickly after the arabs and all the surrounding arab nations declared war on Israel and tried to destroy it.

Nor do they have what is good for the Palestinian people in mind - instead of trying to build a society they have kept generations as homeless refugees with the promise that when Israel is wiped off the map it will be all sun and rainbows.

Comment: So you look at the actions, not the words, and tell me who wants genocide and who wants peace. Who is doing there best to defend their own people and avoid casualties on the other side, and who wants both to be killed.

Comment: @Erwan Quote: [*There is no solution for the Palestinian question except through Jihad. Initiatives, proposals and international conferences are all a waste of time and vain endeavors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Hamas_charter)

Answer (score 5):

Historically, Hamas has not hidden their genocidal intentions. More recently, Hamas has toned down that rethoric for a western audience.

Looking at their original charter, we can see the eliminatory antisemitic intent to [annihilate all Jews](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2023/10/hamas-covenant-israel-attack-war-genocide/675602/). This sentiment has been [repeated in numerous interviews](https://www.adl.org/resources/news/hamas-their-own-words) by Hamas members.

Looking at their most recent actions - the brutal murder, torture, mutilation & kidnapping of Jewish civilians, including men, women, and children - we can see that [genocidal intent in action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegations_of_genocide_in_the_2023_Hamas_attack_on_Israel).

Gaza is - except for the current hostages - [free of Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judenfrei), with good reason. No Jew could live safely in Hamas-controlled land, exactly because of that intent. The only reason Jews can live in the levant is because Hamas doesn't have the means to fully act on that intent.

---

On the other hand, Israel does have the capability to carry out a genocide but is not using it. Instead, they try to reduce civilian casualties in a war against an enemy that uses human shields. There is no information on intentional targeting of specifically civilians without a military justification. That's not to say that all responses are always proportional. But if Israel as a whole - compared to individuals with no significant power - would be intent on genocide, we would see cases of targeted attacks on civilians (as we saw in the 7/10 attack on Israel).

Answer (score 4):

One can't really charge Israel with "intention" of Genocide. for I can't find omniscient to read their minds and hearts. Moreover, over the years Israel left Gaza strip and left several location in the West Bank. To say that " Perhaps Israel would indeed perpetrate genocide if not for the certain global backlash.". Perhaps our neighbor from the next door, wants to kill us if not the law against murder. So lets charge them with murder. Israel could have been more aggressive against the Palestinians - they could have been much more aggressive on 7th October. They didn't.  Also, over the years the Palestinians population have been rising.

Now, Hamas: to quote Hamas that "Hamas is not hostile to Jews because they are Jews. We are hostile to them because they occupied our land" as an argument that their intention is not genocide really not working if one thinks about it for a moment: For they admit they want genocide - but the "genus" is not Jews but Israelis. All of them - including babies, women and even Arabs. even Muslim Arabs (as they did in Oct 7th)

So, as you note, Hamas is very clear about its intentions and demonstrated this in its actions. Again - to say that if Hamas could really destroy Israel they  wouldn't do it -- is hypothetical and not how justice should be made IMO - for we can't really allow ourselves to find out. Hamas is not democracy: what would stop them?

And finally, even the idea that "We[Hamas] are hostile to them because they occupied our land" is wrong. Jews are indigenous to the middle east including Israel. Jews presence in Israel never ceased for thousands of years. They were once many Jews in other middle eastern locations (for hundreds or years) such as current day Iraq or Egypt (Many actually call them "Arab Jews"). But now there are almost none in all those locations. The [Muslim] Arabs prosecute them and stole their lands and properties - even before the state of Israel was born. They were forced to leave and some of them found refuge in current day Israel.

To this one should add, that Israel is not free of Arabs. There are many Arabs living in peace in Israel. some of them indeed indigenous for generations. They are living in Israel freely. This could not be said about Gaza strip for example that is free of Jews (despite for hundreds of years they had presence there)

Answer (score 4):

**Hamas**
Hamas declared goal is "liberation of all Palestine", from the river to the sea. This means eliminating the state of Israel, a UN member, recognized by most states in the world. This is s genocidal goal by definition.

The original [1988 Hamas charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Hamas_charter) was very explicit about the organization genocidal goals:

> The original Charter identifies Hamas as the Muslim Brotherhood in Palestine and declares its members to be Muslims who "fear God and raise the banner of Jihad in the face of the oppressors". The charter states that "our struggle against the Jews is very great and very serious" and **calls for the eventual creation of an *Islamic state in Palestine*, in place of Israel and the Palestinian Territories, and the *obliteration or dissolution of Israel*.** It emphasizes the importance of jihad, stating in article 13, **"There is no solution for the Palestinian question except through Jihad. Initiatives, proposals and international conferences are all a waste of time and vain endeavors."** The charter also states that Hamas is humanistic, and tolerant of other religions as long as they "stop disputing the sovereignty of Islam in this region". The Charter adds that "renouncing any part of Palestine means renouncing part of the religion [of Islam]".

(emphasis is mine)

The more recent [2017 Hamas charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Hamas_charter) watered down the rhetoric, without abandoning the principal goal: the obliteration of Israel and establishment of an Islamic state

> Under the heading "The position toward Occupation and Political Solutions" (paragraphs 18 to 23), the document describes the two-state solution, i.e. the creation of an independent Palestinian state according to the 1967 borders with Jerusalem as its capital, as a "formula of national consensus", but **without giving up the claim to the whole of Palestine, "from the river to the sea", and "without compromising its rejection of the Zionist entity."** Rickard Lagervall viewed this as an "ambiguous formulation". **The two-state solution is seen as a temporary stage; the long-term goal remains the liberation of the whole of Palestine.** The agreements reached in the Oslo Accords are criticized and rejected as incompatible with international law. The state of Israel, created with the help of Western nations, is still regarded as "completely illegal" (bâtil in Arabic, a word that also has religious connotations).

It is also necessary to point out that the 1988 charter was never repealed, so it is unclear whether the new charter replaces it or whether it is intended to mislead the public and Israel - the later theory gain in credibility in view of 7/10 attacks.

**Israel**
Whether Israeli army is committing war crimes, and whether they constitute a governmental policy, which could raise them to a status of genocide is something to prove in a court of law. Israel certainly has never declared such a goal, and until proven guilty cannot be blamed.

**Stated intentions vs. guessing**
Finally, second-guessing Israel's intentions, although a widespread practice, remains but guesswork - which is rightly considered off topic on this SE.

Answer (score 3):

> From the river to the sea, Palestine will be free.

In one of the [surveys](https://www.wsj.com/articles/from-which-river-to-which-sea-anti-israel-protests-college-student-ignorance-a682463b), only 47% of the students who embrace the slogan were able to name the river and the sea. But if, as likely, from Jordan River to the Mediterranean Sea, there is simply no place for Jews remaining.

Comment: Down votes without reason.

Answer (score 1):

Which is worse: an incidental successful partial genocide or a failing intentional complete genocide?

Neither is good.

Hamas has a public position that Jews should be eliminated throughout the region. They explicitly demand genocide. They lack the ability to do so. Their atrocities are committed with atrocious goals.

Israel has the ability to wipe out Gaza. Israel's policies are clearly abhorrent. But their atrocities are committed in the name of rational (if not reasonable) military or strategic goals.

So both are bad. Both can be accused of genocide.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for "a comprehensive set of evidence." That would take the form of quotes, specific actions, detailed analyses etc.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, it's an equation between George Bush and Osama Bin Ladin.

Comment: intent is a necessary component of the crime of genocide, defined by the convention for prevention of genocide.

Comment: @Jacob3 I didn't know that came from Bush. Surprised. It's a structure that helps me better understand this mess, regardless of its source.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you cite the Hamas charter. I think the latest one is from 2017. It makes their views very clear.

Comment: https://www.newsweek.com/watch-madeleine-albright-saying-iraqi-kids-deaths-worth-it-resurfaces-1691193

Comment: The goal of Hamas is the extermination of Israel.  The goal of Israel is to exist.  They are not comparable.  It is not true that Israel's actions are in any way bad.  They have exercised extraordinary restraint.  They have done this time and time again.  Men and women soldiers have died or been mutilated directly because of this restraint.  Men, women, and children have died because of this restraint.